# CSS set ::before width equal to content

Tags: html, css

I have a `span` with text inside and the `::before` pseudo-element.
I need to set the width of `::before` equal to the width of `span`. It will be the underline of the text.

```
<li class="menu-list-item">
  <a href="index.html">
    <span>Home</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

I've done this using JS (by setting width to the `li`), but I need a CSS solution. I know I can set `left:0; right:0;`, but I need to set exactly the width

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can you please provide the CSS of the `::before`?

Comment: Please provide an example of what the underline is supposed to look like. Ideally, include your current CSS approach.

Comment: Please use `text-decoration: underline;`  on span also you can use `border-bottom` css on span

Comment: I need to animate the appearance of the underline (slide from left to right), so I must use the `::before`

Comment: Please don't repost the same question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59842488/css-set-width-equal-to-inline-parent

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you need?

```
.menu-list-item a span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-list-item a span::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/MustafaOmarIbrahim/pen/ZEYVmBX)

Comment: If I set the `width: 100%`, `::before` width will be equal to `li`, not to `span`. Now it works because I set the width of `li` using JS, but I want to find only CSS solution